# Why I'm getting " void value not ignored as it ought to be"?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am writing this program and and getting error bellow,please any one help to get out of this rid.(https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/array-of-alternate-ve-and-ve-nos/0).Or can you people explain in which scenario we get this type of error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int rearrange(int array[],int N)
{
    vector<int> vec1;
    vector<int> vec2;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        if(array[i]<0)
        vec1.push_back(array[i]);
        else
        vec2.push_back(array[i]);
    }
    int size_vec1;
    int size_vec2;
    size_vec1=vec1.size();
    size_vec2=vec2.size();
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
    {   

        if(j/2==0 || size_vec2==0 )
        {
             array[j]=vec1.pop_back();
             size_vec1-=1;
        }
        else
        {
             array[j]=vec2.pop_back();
             size_vec2-=1;
        }

    }
}

void print_rearrangearray(int array[],int N)
{
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        cout<<array[i]<<" ";
    }
}
int main() {
    int T;
    cin>>T;
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
        int N;
        cin>>N;
        int array[N];
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
           cin>>array[i];
       rearrange(array,N);
       print_rearrangearray(array,N); 

    }
    return 0;
}
```

And I am getting the following error.

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int rearrange(int*, int)’:
prog.cpp:24:22: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
              array[j]=vec1.pop_back();
                      ^
prog.cpp:29:22: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
              array[j]=vec2.pop_back();
```

Comment: Detect the exact line of the code. Then write a minimal example which shows the problem, instead of pasting your code. That way, the kind reader might give you an answer.

Answer (score 3):

[`std::vector::pop_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back) has return type `void`, which means it doesn't return anything.

First get the value, then, pop it:

```
array[j] = vec1.back(); // Get last item
vec1.pop_back(); // remove last item
```

Same goes for `vec2`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet which demonstrates your problem could be reduced to this:

```
#include<vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
    int i = v.pop_back();
    return 0;
}
```

Now, if you have a look at [`std::vector::pop_back()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/pop_back/), then you will see that the return type of `pop_back()` is `void`, hence your error.

Comment: Thanks I was unaware that return type of std::vector::pop_back() is void thanks to let me know.